# Running PHP code with AJAX in real time?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have PHP page called (`jQuery_puff.php`) which only holds a javascript/jQuery in it.

The jquery in that PHP is this:

```
<?php
echo '<script>
$( "#myButton" ).click(function() {
$( "#myDiv" ).effect( "puff", "slow" );
$( "#myDiv" ).toggle( "puff" );
});
</script>';
?>
```

I have included this PHP page within another PHP file like so:

```
<?php include "jQuery_puff.php"; ?>
```

what the first code inside the `jQuery_puff.php` does is that it will apply a jquery puff effect to the `#myDiv` everytime the user clicks on the `#myButton`.

Everything works as they should. so far so good. but this is only happens for one user (client side).

**Now My Question:**

Is there any way to run this PHP page in real time for all the users using AJAX?

For example the **USER 1** clicks on the `#myButton` and the **USER 2**, **USER 3** etc will also see the puff effect being applied to the `#myDiv` ?

I thought about using something like this But this doesn't do anything!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myButton").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myOwn.php',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    checkForNewData2();

                }
            });
        });

        var intervalID2 = setInterval(checkForNewData2, 500);
    });

        function checkForNewData2() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'jQuery_puff.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#data").html(data.data);

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

am I in the right direction? or...?

Comment: Not without using webSockets or something to that effect to push data to the browser. If you try to do this with just ajax and php yo'ure going to tie up 1 entire HTTPD thread of the (in general) 2 offered by each browser. This will inevitably lead to the browser 'hanging' and a force close being required to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is `jQuery_puff.php` really only going to have javascript in it? If so  I don't understand why you're using `.ajax` instead of `.on("click", function(){})`

Comment: @pasta12, Yes, it only going to hold the javascript in it. The reason for using AJAX is because i thought I could use AJAX calls so the puff effect will be applied to the Div in real time.

Comment: Oh I see for all users. That might be much more difficult.

Comment: You will need a push or you could look into long polling.

Comment: @pasta12, which one is easier to learn and implement into my code?

Comment: @user2808228 probably long polling.